IPTables NAT Forwarding SSH
I have a VPS with an IPSEC VPN using Strong Swan to a partner network. They are expecting all traffic from my network to come from one NAT'd address. I have the NAT set up successfully outbound to the partner network and can SSH to a server there from my VPS. I'm trying to SSH from the server on the partner network to my VPS and I'm missing something with my iptables NAT rules.
Partner network is 10.143.2.16/28 (coming from host .19)
The NAT they're expecting from me is: 10.2.252.47
My VPS IP (sanitized since it's a public IP): 1.2.3.4
I'm trying to SSH from 10.143.2.19 to 10.2.252.47 (the NAT of the VPS, and trying to access SSH on the VPS 1.2.3.4)
Appreciate the help!
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

DNAT       tcp  --  10.143.2.16/28anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh to:1.2.3.4

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination         

ts-postrouting  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

MASQUERADE  all  --  10.8.0.0/24anywhere            

SNAT       all  --  anywhere             10.143.2.16/28to:10.2.252.47


Since the gateway, source, and destination are all on different subnets, does this answer your question? https://serverfault.com/a/1017016/411612
